# .htaccess reference with examples

Tags: .htaccess, reference

Need link, if it exist, to good and full .htaccess reference with examples.
Thanks.

Comment: Try Google. This isn't a search engine.

Comment: The only link you'll need: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=htaccess+tutorial

Comment: Guess people is willing to help if your efforts face a problem. Note the word "efforts".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about the actual documentation for apache. [httpd.apache.org howto htaccess](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html).

Answer (score 2):

http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-tips-and-tricks.html

Answer (score 0):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/htaccess.html

You can do so many things with `.htaccess` file, that there are probably no comprehensive set of examples.